# Contact form 7 recaptcha - translate message

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, recaptcha

I'm using contact form 7 and I'm wondering how can I translate the message "Please verify that you are not a robot." in french.

The message "I'm not a robot" is correctly translated in french but not the error message.

Regards.

Comment: To be clear, you somehow changed the settings of Contact Form 7 so that it is in French language instead of english and it works for some parts of the system, but not all, is that your problem?

Comment: @TimBourguignon Thanks. Everything works fine with my contact form, the recaptcha message 'I'm not a robot' is also in french. Only the error message "Please verify that you are not a robot" is in english.

Comment: Not sure if it relates to your problem: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-set-the-recaptcha-language

Comment: @TimBourguignon. Not exactly, but thank you.